# CNAME setting of Google App Engine SSL, same for all domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to use Google App Engine custom domain ssl.

I have already a domain(DomainA) which use App Engigne SSL for an application id.

CNAME setting of the domain is "ghs-svc-https-cXX.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com"(XX is 2 digit number), and working well.

Now I want to use App Engine SSL for another domain(DomainB) for another application id.

Is the CNAME setting of DomainA and DomainB same?

I want to use SNI+VIP for both domain.

Or 2 digit number of CNAME setting is different per domain?

I may be able to check the CNAME setting of the DomainB on Google Apps SSL setting page,
but I cannot select VIP for DomainB because I don't pass the first checkout yet.

Comment: I can check the CNAME setting in my Google Apps setting page. "ghs-svc-https-cXXXX.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com"(XXXX is 4digit number).Probably the setting is different per domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a separate VIP for each domain name.